# What is the stored procedures performance compared to embedded SQL in various RDBMs?

Tags: database, performance, stored-procedures

From my experience with DB2 on Z/OS there is no difference between embedded SQL and stored procedures as both get compiled to native code. On the other hand I know that in Oracle there is a huge difference - is it true and how is it in other DBs? Please provide some links to support your claims.

Comment: "both get compiled to native code": really? I can understand a query plan being compiled, but to native code??

Comment: Are they not? At least the "external procedures" are (AFAIK there are also "SQL procedures", but the external can be written in just about any language and compiled and stored as regular native code).Granted, I've written the stored procs in COBOL on mainframe, so it may a little different elsewhere

Comment: http://www.devx.com/ibm/Article/27818

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Embedded SQL` in Oracle means that you can embed SQL statements right into your `C/C++` code. There is a tool called `Pro*C` that parses these statements and wraps them into `OCI` calls.

This is of course a client side tool, I don't see how it may be compared to a server-side stored procedure.

If by "embedded SQL" you mean `anonymous blocks`, then there is some performance decrease when a block is called for the first time, because is needs to be compiled. Stored procedured are kept precompiled in the database.

As soon as the anonymous block is called for the first time and kept in the cache, there is no performance difference.

**P. S.** There is thing called native compilation in `PL/SQL` that allows compiling the procedures and storing them in the shared libraries on the disk.

That can only be applied to stored procedures, but it's only useful for `CPU` intensive tasks, not for complex `SQL` queries.